# change default application on iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there any way to change the default application? E.g. change mailto: behavior to launch 3rd party application when user selects an email address anywhere on iphone OR launch SMS application when user selects a phone number.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicolas is correct.  To use some of the default applications (you mentioned SMS) you simply need to call the appropriate URL handler.

Please refer to: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html

You cannot override the default handlers.  Apple have made it very clear that they do not want to *confuse* the user by providing applications that duplicate basic iPhone functionality.  The most famous case is Google Voice (http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/07/27/apple-is-growing-rotten-to-the-core-and-its-likely-atts-fault/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URL handlers. I'm not sure if you can override default handlers (mailto: http:...), but have a look at this guide:

http://www.mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/